# Setting UIImageView.frame causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS occasionally

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ios6, uiimageview

I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I've tried all the suggestions regarding bad access without luck.  I know that it is caused when I set a UIImageView frame.

This is the code...

```
_backImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback_brothers_royal"]];
CGRect imageFrame = _backImageView.frame;
imageFrame.origin.x = -9;
imageFrame.origin.y = -9;
imageFrame.size.width = 151;
imageFrame.size.height = 225;
_backImageView.frame = imageFrame;
```

Backtrace:

```
0   0x33cf3a22 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) actionForLayer:forKey:] ()
1   0x33aa201e in -[CALayer actionForKey:] ()
2   0x33aa1fce in actionForKey(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, NSString*) ()
3   0x33aa1eba in CA::Layer::begin_change(CA::Transaction*, unsigned int, objc_object*&) ()
4   0x33a9d9e6 in CA::Layer::set_position(CA::Vec2<double> const&, bool) ()
5   0x33a9d8a2 in -[CALayer setPosition:] ()
6   0x33a9d832 in -[CALayer setFrame:] ()
7   0x33cf2aec in -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] ()
8   0x33cf2814 in -[UIImageView _setViewGeometry:forMetric:] ()
9   0x33cf2752 in -[UIImageView setFrame:] ()
10  0x0006cd88 in -[CardView loadBack]
```

Comment: Try to call the image with its extension, example: `[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback_brothers_royal.png"]` or jpg, or whatever.

Comment: All these answers which are basically telling to do the same thing in a different way. Your problem is not with this code but somewhere else, possibly a weak pointer where it should be strong. Also you need to show more context for this code, where is it running, when is it called etc etc.

Comment: hmmm ... zombie in the target [UIView(CALayerDelegate) actionForLayer:forKey:] , have you profiled for zombies ?

Comment: Are you doing this inside some kind of animation code that you are not showing us???? That could be realllly important for us to know...

Comment: @Malloc: Missing the filename extension would not cause `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. That is a completely different kind of problem.

Comment: When you run under Instruments using its Zombies template and try to reproduce the problem, what do you find?

Answer (score -3):

Alway's try to set your ImageView frame Like this:
    YourImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x_position,y_position,width,height);

Comment: This would, at best, change nothing; it certainly would not solve the problem.